# instead of xpath what can i select from the below code

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Please help me to find locator in this case as id is dynamic and it changes every time when I refresh the page.

type="text" also I will not be able to use because, for the next fields, eveything is same from the down code except, the label changes from the "first name" to the "last name" and so on.

So I should be selecting something in terms of the first name which is mentioned in the label tag below.

Please anyone can help me in this case.

```
  <input class="md-input-element ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" id="md-
  input-4-input" spellcheck="false" type="text">
  <!--template bindings={}-->

  <label class="md-input-placeholder md-float md-empty" for="md-input-
  4-input">First name * <!--template bindings={}--></label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preceding-sibling` or `following-sibling` feature from `xpath`. As per code mentioned above your `xpath` should be like this:

```
//input[@type='text'][following-sibling::label[contains(text(),'First name')]]
```

But I think in html `label` should be first then `input`, if that is case please try below one:

```
//input[@type='text'][preceding-sibling::label[contains(text(),'First name')]]
```

Comment: in case of preceding sibling what should i write

Comment: I gave you both solution, is any of them not working?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: showing me this error as i have used it as :driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//input[@type='text'][preceding-sibling::label[contains(text(),'First name')]]"))
     .sendKeys(ExcelUtils.getCellData(row, 2, Constants.DONATION_RECIEPT));

Comment: my doubt is u have written preceding sibling ,what should i write in place of  preceding sibling,because the preceding sibling is input

Comment: Please use that as: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][pr‌​eceding-sibling::lab‌​el[contains(text(),'‌​First name')]]")) .sendKeys(ExcelUtils.getCellData(row, 2, Constants.DONATION_RECIEPT));

Comment: Basically the provided xpath is to find input field. And sibling is just for reference to locate exact element.

Comment: //input[@type='text'][following-sibling::label[contains(text(),'First name')]]

Answer (score 0):

you can get the css selector from the class (can't do by className if it has spaces in the class name so use css, put a "." at the beginning and replace any spaces with a ".")

```
@FindBy(css = ".md-input-element.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched")
private WebElement elementMDInputTouched;

@FindBy(css = ".md-input-placeholder.md-float.md-empty")
private WebElement elementMDInputEmpty;
```